# Extract part of a tar archive to another tar archive file

Tags: tar

I have a tar archive that contains several big directories. Often I need one or two of those directories but I still need them in a tar archive.

Is there a more performant way then extracting the directories from the archive and re-archiving them? I was hoping for something similar to "split" but I don't want to do it on file size.

Comment: Create tar file for each directory. Also you can try with `zip` (again one per directory)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't have access to the directories, only the tar file.

Comment: So extract them from `tar`

Comment: @RomeoNinov You could answer that there is not another way =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be done in your case (to speedup archive operations) is to recreate the `tar` in form of individual `tar` files, one per directory. So you will need to extract only one archive (completely). Without waiting to reach the place in the `tar` where particular directory is stored (as it it at the moment).

Also you can try to apply `zip` instead of `tar` for creation of the archives. This will speedup the reading operations (because you will have compression and smaller files). But this will cost you more memory usage (for decompress) and processor power (same reason).

All those points depend heavy from the hardware you use (speed of disks, filesystem where the archive is located, filesystem where the files are extracted, amount of free memory, CPU usage and power)